# How to run program before explorer.exe when the system start?

Tags: c#

I'm programming in C# under win7 and windows XP. My software needs to auto start when the system starts. So I modified the registry to conform to this requirement, but when I start the computer, the desktop will show for a while. I know this is because explorer.exe runs before the auto-start program.  I want to how to let my program run before explorer so that the desktop could not be shown? Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: You can avoid putting things like "[in C#]" in your titles. That is what the tags are for :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try making it a Windows Service (Visual Studio project type)?

And the setting the service to autostart.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are [Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Do be advised though, that explorer.exe sort of *is* Windows. So I doubt you will achieve whatever it is you are trying to achieve.